# Code for Wemos d1 mini that converts Cyrillic alphabet to Morse code

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, esp8266

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
const char *ssid = "YourSSID";         // SSID точки доступа
const char *password = "YourPassword"; // Пароль для точки доступа
ESP8266WebServer server(80);
const int ledPin = D4; // Пин, к которому подключен светодиод
const char *morseAlphabet[] = {
  ".-",    // А
  "-...",  // Б
  ".--",   // В
  "--.",   // Г
  "-..",   // Д
  ".",     // Е
  "..-.",  // Ж
  "--..",  // З
  "..",    // И
  ".---",  // Й
  "-.-",   // К
  ".-..",  // Л
  "--",    // М
  "-.",    // Н
  "---",   // О
  ".--.",  // П
  "--.-",  // Р
  "...",   // С
  "-",     // Т
  "..-",   // У
  "...-",  // Ф
  "....",  // Х
  "-.-.",  // Ц
  "---.",  // Ч
  "----",  // Ш
  "--.-",  // Щ
  "-..-",  // Ъ
  "-.--",  // Ы
  "-.--.", // Ь
  "..-..", // Э
  ".-.-",  // Ю
  "--.--"  // Я
};
void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Подключение к Wi-Fi
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, handleRoot);
  server.on("/", HTTP_POST, handlePost);
  server.begin();
}
void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
void handleRoot() {
  String html = "<html><body>";
  html += "<h1>Преобразование текста в азбуку Морзе</h1>";
  html += "<form method='post' action='/'>";
  html += "Текст на русском языке: <input type='text' name='inputText'>";
  html += "<input type='submit' value='Отправить'>";
  html += "</form>";
  html += "</body></html>";
  server.send(200, "text/html", html);
}
void handlePost() {
  String inputText = server.arg("inputText");
  String morseText = textToMorse(inputText);
  server.send(200, "text/html", "Текст на азбуке Морзе: " + morseText);
  flashMorseCode(morseText);
}
String textToMorse(String text) {
  String morseCode = "";
  text.toLowerCase();
  for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char currentChar = text[i];
    if (currentChar == ' ') {
      morseCode += " ";
    } else if (isAlpha(currentChar)) {
      int index = currentChar - 'a';
      morseCode += morseAlphabet[index];
      morseCode += " ";
    }
  }
  return morseCode;
}
void flashMorseCode(String morse) {
  for (int i = 0; i < morse.length(); i++) {
    char symbol = morse[i];
    if (symbol == '.') {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      delay(100); // Длительность точки
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      delay(100); // Пауза между символами
    } else if (symbol == '-') {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      delay(300); // Длительность тире
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      delay(100); // Пауза между символами
    } else if (symbol == ' ') {
      delay(300); // Пауза между словами
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make a code for Wemos d1 mini that does this. wemos creates a hotspot and a local site. On which there will be a field for text input and a send button. When I enter text and click the button, it should convert to morse code (for the Cyrillic alphabet). Then this morse code text was output by blinking LED. But not everything is not so smooth, English alphabet, but Cyrillic alphabet is not. Can someone tweak it, just my authority on this is over

To be honest, I don't understand
why it doesn't convert the Cyrillic alphabet. I've tried everything I can think of already

Comment: replace `isAlpha(currentChar)` with `currentChar >= 'а' && currentChar <= 'я'`, don't forget that Cyrillic has capitals as well

Comment: @IłyaBursov Case is not represented in Morse code.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Morse_code

Comment: @TomServo but input on web page has case

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is most likely because Cyrillic characters are outside ASCII meaning that they need 2 bytes to encode each character and I am not sure how arduino String handles that (if at all) and what the html page actually sends.

You could test sending one by one character and getting it's byte(s) value and then use that to map the morse code.

On the other hand, I wouldn't bother doing it on the ESP side but rather have Javascript handle it in your web page.

Here is a quick and dirty example that when you submit your text in the page does your conversion to morse and sends the ready morse code as a string to your ESP server.
It basically replaces your "textToMorse()" completely

```
void handlePost(){
  String morseText = server.arg("inputText"); //no need to textToMorse()
```

Try replacing your html with this one and see if it works, you may need to do a bit of tweaking and I've found that I had to include **meta charset="utf-8"** in the html head for it to work.

Also, note that I am using **id='inputText'** not **name='inputText'**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
   </head>
   <script>
    function textToMorse(form){
        let morseMap = {'а':'.-','б':'-...','в':'.--','г':'--.','д':'-..','е':'.','ж':'..-.','з':'--..','и':'..','й':'.---','к':'-.-','л':'.-..','м':'--','н':'-.','о':'---','п':'.--.','р':'--.-','с':'...','т':'-','у':'..-','ф':'...-','х':'....','ц':'-.-.','ч':'---.','ш':'----','щ':'--.-','ъ':'-..-','ы':'-.--','ь':'-.--.','э':'..-..','ю':'.-.-','я':'--.--'}

        let text = form.inputText.value
        let morseOutput = ''
        for(let i = 0;i < text.length;i++){
            let char = text[i].toLowerCase()
            //this is a shorthand expression to save the storage space on the ESP
            morseOutput += (char != ' ') ? (morseMap[char] ? morseMap[char] : '') : ' ' 

            //you could also write it something like this
            // let morseChar = ' '
            // if(char != ' '){
            //     morseChar = morseMap[char]
            //     if(morseChar == undefined){ //will happen if it's a non cyrillic char
            //         morseChar = '' //empty string
            //     }
            // }
            // morseOutput += morseChar
        }

        form.inputText.value = morseOutput //replace the text in the field with the morse code values
        return true
    }
   </script>
<body>
<form method='post' onsubmit='return textToMorse(this)' action='/'>
    <input type='text' id='inputText'>
    <input type='submit' value='Отправить'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've written this really quickly so you may need to recheck the code but it may give you some ideas